# How can I calculate total hours of journey between 2 corelocation objects?

Tags: core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

How to calculate total hours of journey between 2 corelocation objects ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the total distance D, assume a velocity profile at each point, and divide the total distance by the average velocity.  It's an easier calculation if you assume a constant velocity for the whole trip; accounting for stops, starts, accels and decels will complicate the problem a great deal.

Comment: I used "distanceFromLocation" method to get the distance between 2 core locations, how to assume the velocity, is it a random number ?

Comment: Velocity is not random, it's the speed you are traveling between the two points.

Comment: I've actually studied physics, @progrmr.  I know what velocity is.  Your comment is almost a tautology.

Comment: my speed comment was meant for @Dee